# Storing Arrays of Structs in external files in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I'm working on a homework assignment for my CS162 class which requires me to make a program that allows the user to input their class plan for college.  The user inputs classes they have taken, are currently taken, and/or plan on taking, with the categories of: department/class number, class name, term/year, whether or not the class is required for their major, and any additional comments.  Then, the program is supposed to store this invermation with external data files so that the classes are stored and won't be lost.  The program should be able to store up to 60 classes in memory.

I know how to create arrays of strucs and I know the basics behind external files, but I guess I'm having trouble combining the two (I'm a newbie here, so sorry if this is really basic!)

Here's what I have so far:

```
struct college_class
{
    char dept_classnumber;
    char class_name;
    char term_year;
    char is_required;
    char comments;
    char grade;
}

college_class[60]

int main()
{
    int n;
    char again;
    for(n=0;n<60;n++)
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"Enter department and class number (e.g. CS162): ";
            getline (cin,college_class[n].dept_classnumber);
            cout<<"Enter class name (e.g. Intro to Computer Science): ";
            getline (cin,college_class[n].class_name);
            cout<<"Enter the term and year the class was/will be taken: ";
            getline (cin, college_class[n],term_year;
            cout<<"Enter whether or not this class is required for your major: ";
            getline (cin,college_class[n],is_required);
            cout<<"Enter any additional comments here: ";
            getline (cin, college_class[n],comments);
            cout<<"Would you like to enter another class?(y/n)";
            cin>>again;
        }
        while(again == 'y' || again == 'Y' && i<60)
    }
```

Is this the right direction in terms of getting the user input?  My other question is, how do you incorporate the external file into this so that everything the user inputs is stored into the file?  Sorry if this is a little vague, and I'm obviously not looking for my  homework to be done for me - I'm just looking for a little direction to get started here.

I know that writing on a text file looks like this, for example:

```
ofstream my file ("example");
if(myfile.is_open()))
{
   myfile <<"blah blah blah. \n";
   myfile.close();
}
```

...I'm just not sure how to make this work for arrays of structs.

Comment: `struct class` is this valid? I never tried that but I expect a compiler error. Also in here `"Enter department and class number (e.g. "CS162"): "` you should escape those quotes inside the string, i.e. `"Enter department and class number (e.g. \"CS162\"): "` Do you know how to work with files? Then show something that you tried.

Comment: @MariusBancila: [No, it's not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d12860e784b6f577). `class` is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier.

Comment: That's what I was saying... :)

Comment: my bad; I should've used a different word there, sorry.  And as for external files... I edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with you code.
First of all, you have to create a variable for your college_class array.
Eg.:

```
college_class myCollegeClass[60]
```

and use that when asking input

```
getline (cin, myCollegeClass[n].term_year;)
```

you accidentally used commas on some lines there, watch out for that

Furthermore, a char can only hold one character, which won't be enough if you want to hold the full class name, use strings in your struct.

```
struct college_class
{
   string class_name;
   ...
}
```

You used a nested loop there, which will repeat your questions 60 times, regardless if you said you didn't want to input anything else.

I'd suggest

```
int i=0;
char again = 'y';
while(again != 'n' && again != 'N' && i<60)
{
   ...
   i++
}
```

As for the file, after you have your inputs, just loop though your myCollegeClass array and write the data to the file. Eg.:

```
myfile << myCollegeClass[i].class_name;
```

Comment: thank you! this is just what I needed to get started.